# Remove unicode characters from a string

Tags: c++, regex, unicode, count

Below is my code snippet where I have been able to remove some escape characters. But the problem is that I cannot remove unicode characters from given string NewOutput read from ParseLine(). Also I want to count the number of lines that contains unicode.

For example the string NewOutput have 3 lines as:

> @KayKay121 dragged me to the library. Now I have to be productive \ud83d\udc94 https://t.co/HjZR3d5QaQ (timestamp: Thu Oct 29 17:51:50 +0000 2015)
>
> 6A has decided to postpone final vote until appeals are heard by executive board. What seems set: 7 regions. (timestamp: Thu Oct 29 17:51:51 +0000 2015)
>
> @i_am_sknapp Thanks for following us, Seth. (timestamp: Thu Oct 29 18:10:49 +0000 2015)

It would be great help for me :) Thanks!!!

```
if (readtweetfile.is_open()) 
{
    while (!readtweetfile.eof()) 
    {
        getline(readtweetfile,output);
        ParseLine(output,NewOutput);
        std::string unicod_string = output;

        if(NewOutput!=" ")
        {   
            std::string firstChar="Check";
            std::string secondChar;
            std::string checkingChar="";
            for (std::string::iterator it = NewOutput.begin(), end = NewOutput.end(); it != end; ++it)
            {
                if(firstChar=="Check")
                    firstChar = *it;
                else
                {
                    secondChar = *it;
                    checkingChar = firstChar + secondChar;

                    if(checkingChar=="\\\"")
                    {
                        writetweetfile << secondChar ; 
                        firstChar="Check";
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(checkingChar=="\\/")
                    {
                        writetweetfile << secondChar; 
                        firstChar="Check";
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(checkingChar=="\\\'")
                    {
                        writetweetfile << secondChar; 
                        firstChar="Check";
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(checkingChar=="\\\n")
                    {
                        writetweetfile << " " ; 
                        firstChar="Check";
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(checkingChar=="\\\t")
                    {
                        writetweetfile <<  " "; 
                        firstChar="Check";
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(checkingChar=="\\  ")
                    {
                        writetweetfile <<  " "; 
                        firstChar="Check";
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(checkingChar=="\\\\")
                    {
                        writetweetfile << secondChar;
                        firstChar="Check";
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(checkingChar=="\\u")
                    {
                        writetweetfile << "unicode";
                        firstChar="Check";
                        continue;
                    }

                    writetweetfile << firstChar;
                    firstChar=secondChar;
                }   
            }
        }
        writetweetfile << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting those strings? Is that file saved in some file format? Eg. if the file is JSON, just use a JSON parser, it will decode these escapes. Second, `\ud83d\udc94` is a surrogate pair (probably for an emoji) for one single character.

Answer (score 0):

Well without actually knowing what you would like the output to be for your 3 samples - I came up with this

```
\\(u|U)[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\|\t|\n
```

This will find unicode and escape characters

If you need something different, revise the question with more examples and more importantly, what you would like the finished output to be.